# Empty parameter in Crystal Reports Not showing NULL

Tags: crystal-reports, null

I have a parameter that prompts the user to enter a value.
If that field is left blank I would think that the parameter would be NULL.

If I run:

```
isnull({?Param}) then
run this code...
```

The code does not run

BUT if I run it like:

```
hasvalue({?Param})
run this code...
```

The code runs!

Any idea why an empty param field does not return NULL?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know,

`hasvalue` is used to check if a parameter has a value specified whereas `IsNULL` is mainly used in conjunction with a database field.

Which is why it may be behaving like that in your case.